# Ghost project icon in Xcode laucher

Tags: xcode

Every time Xcode's launcher opens, I see the icon of a project that has been deleted for ages. I double click it, then the error message appears saying it's no longer in my system, but the icon continues to show up in the launcher.

I've already tried:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: File > Open Recent > Clear Menu

Comment: @user3439894 that worked!!  = )
Don't you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Xcode opens, by default, it shows the Welcome to Xcode window upon which there is a list of recent projects one can select to open.  To clear this list click: File > Open Recent > Clear Menu

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all the recent projects in system preferences > general and change the number of recent items to 0. Every time you open xcode now no recent projects will show up.

Comment: Thks man!!! = )